# bootstrap p value

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, bootstrap, finance

Using our baseline bootstrap, for each fund i, we draw a sample with replacement from the fund residuals that are saved in the first step above, creating a
pseudo–time series of resampled residuals, {ˆb
i,tε
, tε = sb
Ti0
, ... , sb
Ti1
}, where b is an
index for the bootstrap number (so b = 1 for bootstrap resample number 1),
and where each of the time indices sb
Ti0
, ... , sb
Ti1 are drawn randomly from
[Ti0,...,Ti1] in such a way that reorders the original sample of Ti1 − Ti0 + 1
residuals for fund i. Conversely, the original chronological ordering of the factor returns is unaltered; we relax this restriction in a different version of our
bootstrap below.
Next, we construct a time series of pseudo–monthly excess returns for
this fund, imposing the null hypothesis of zero true performance (αi = 0, or,
equivalently, tˆ
αˆi = 0),

rb
i,t = βˆiRMRFt + sˆiSMBt + hˆ
iHMLt + pˆiPR1YRt + ˆ b
i,tε

, (4)
for t = Ti0, ... , Ti1 and tε = sb
Ti0
, ... , sb
Ti1
. As equation (4) indicates, this sequence
of artificial returns has a true alpha (and t-statistic of alpha) that is zero by
construction. However, when we next regress the returns for a given bootstrap
sample, b, on the Carhart factors, a positive estimated alpha (and t-statistic)
may result, since that bootstrap may have drawn an abnormally high number
of positive residuals, or, conversely, a negative alpha (and t-statistic) may result
if an abnormally high number of negative residuals are drawn.
Repeating the above steps across all funds i = 1, ... , N, we arrive at
a draw from the cross section of bootstrapped alphas. Repeating this for
all bootstrap iterations, b = 1, ... , 1,000, we then build the distribution of
these cross-sectional draws of alphas, {αˆ b
i , i = 1, ... , N}, or their t-statistics, {tˆb
αˆi
, i = 1, ... , N}, that result purely from sampling variation while imposing the null of a true alpha that is equal to zero. For example, the distribution of alphas (or t-statistics) for the top fund is constructed as the distribution of the maximum alpha (or, maximum t-statistic) generated across
all bootstraps.
This iteration was suggested by Kosowski et al (2006) https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/j.1540-6261.2006.01015.x
the last step of their iteration confuse me. How exactly can we compute the cross-sectional bootstrap values and rank the funds on its basis?

Comment: "Fund i": Is this finance? Please describe your situation/context with more details!

Comment: Yes, it is related to finance. Fund i mean a specific mutual fund the performance of which is being evaluated.  i = 1,2,3.......N.